# WPF with C++, is it possible?

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, user-interface

I have my main program in C++, but now I need to build a beautiful application and I know that WPF is easy and makes for beautiful apps. Can WPF work with C++ or C# and C++? (If yes, how?) Is WPF the best thing for me?

Comment: this won't help you with current Windows, but it looks like W8 will have good native C++ support for fancy GUIs: http://arstechnica.com/microsoft/news/2011/06/windows-8-for-software-developers-the-longhorn-dream-reborn.ars

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use WPF in a managed C++ project, but you're better off keeping your C++ in a separate assembly and referencing it from a C# or VB WPF project.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am a little bit a noob :) so how can I do that easily? Do you have a good tutorial or can you say me how to do because I found plenty tutorials in C# and WPF but I didn't find something for C++ and WPF.

Comment: There aren't any tutorials on C++ and WPF because WPF is modern and works better with a modern language like C#. So, like I say, create your WPF user interface using C#, then reference your C++ assembly. Here is an example of how to do that using `DllImport`: http://www.dotnetperls.com/dllimport

Comment: So I should create a Class Library project in C++ with Visual2010, to create my DLLs and use this DLLs in my second application in C#? That's it? Or it's not this kind of project may be for C++?

Comment: Class Library project in C++ will create a *managed C++* DLL. DllImport will use an existing *native* C++. It depends on your code. Make sure you understand the difference between managed and native C++ first.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can develop a GUI using WPF framework in *Managed* C+ or C++/CLI. But they're not Standard C++, hence not cross-platform.

If you just want a GUI for your application written in C++, then you may try [Qt](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/index.html) as well. The advantage in Qt is that its completely in C++. Not Microsoft Managed C++. The second advantage is that its cross-platform toolkit. That means, you can run your app in Windows, Linux, Mac, and on other machines as well.

Have a look at its documentation

- [Qt Reference Documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/index.html)

It has lots of tools for fast development such as [Qt Creator](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtcreator-2.2/index.html), [Qt Designer](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/designer-manual.html) and others. You can see all of them by browsing the above link.

Comment: Qt can create fast charts? I am working on a financial app so my charts will have something like 5k of points and lines so something fluent will be sweet. :)

Comment: @Nazka: Qt will create charts much faster than WPF, believe me.

Comment: @Nazka: Just download the toolkit, its very small in size; will not take much time to download. Download and see its demo examples which comes with the toolkit itself. They're very pretty and cool.

Comment: Qt Creator and Qt Designer sound good. :) I am going far of my primary question but in Qt it's easy to build for exemple an option bar with a list of string? Edit : yes I will try Qt

Comment: @Nazka: Qt is a very very matured toolkit. You can do anything with it. Also, its easy. It has even declarative language like WPF. So everything becomes very easy, and development can be very fast.

Answer (score -5):

WPF is dead along with Silverlight, remember, MS says its HTML5 only from now on :)

Using WPF in your C++ app can be achieved using [hwndSource](http://devonethatdevelops.wordpress.com/2007/10/30/wpf-win32-interop-with-hwndsource/), but its not the optimal solution, for that you will have to create C# or VB.NET GUI app, and use it to communicate with your C++ app via some form of IPC.

There are alternatives, probably the best one is to write your GUI using [Qt](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/), which is very well respected. You can get similar features to WPF by writing using [QML](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2009/05/13/qt-declarative-ui/) alongside the old forms-based system (which means you get all the development speed of using the old, boring text boxes and the like, and the fancy GUI benefits of using the new declarative UI system, all in the same system. sweet).

Of course, a decent option is to make your app into a back-end server process and call it from a web-server based HTML5 UI. That's pretty future proof, easy to deploy to clients, and as modern as you're likely to get.

Comment: In your last solution, the goal is to build a web site? Or a web service? What is the best tool to have an interface between my C++ app and a web site? (just a great Database with mySql may be?)

Comment: WPF+SL dead? Cite your sources, please, because at this point that is just an ugly rumor. If you're just projecting, please don't do it as if it were fact.

Comment: @djdanlib: its a rumour that you'd be advised to keep listening to as its not exactly totally unsubstantiated. Here's today's installment: http://www.i-programmer.info/news/81-web-general/2640-skydrive-drops-silverlight.html The trouble with smoke is that often there really is a fire underneath it. It might not be true, but that doesn't mean you can completely ignore it.

Comment: @Nazka: a website - one that does not run its server side code in the webserver. A web site is just another application, one where the gui lives in the browser instead of being run directly. You need to be able to call methods in your C++ app in some way from some webserver code, but that could be anything - socket, RPC, command line even - but it needs a way to expose methods that a client can call.

Comment: I have been following it closely, and Microsoft has said no such thing - in fact, they are saying quite the opposite. You need look no further than the president of Microsoft's Server & Tools division: http://team.silverlight.net/announcement/pdc-and-silverlight/  - but if you want to look further, try Scott Guthrie: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/11/04/silverlight-questions.aspx ... Let's both agree to follow the issue on our own, so we don't get into an argument and make things go any more off-topic.

Comment: WPF is alive and well in 2019 and beyond. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/overview/index

Comment: @ScottHutchinson they still have [WinForms docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/) too. Look back on djdanlib saying the "+SL dead?". Nobody wanted to see my little smiley though, oh well.

Comment: No, I did not notice the smiley. Maybe you'd consider editing your answer to make it less misleading in 2019.

Comment: @ScottHutchinson or maybe you could read the answer in its entirely instead of suggesting I'm at fault.

Comment: Clearly, your answer is perfect as is. Nobody has the right to suggest otherwise. Don't touch it.